# How is reverse osmosis even possible for desalination?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, ions, osmosis

I don't understand how reverse osmosis for desalination is possible for existing RO membranes of pore size 10 angstroms (A) if the radius of a sodium atom is 3.14 A, chloride is 3.7 A and maximum radius of a water molecule is 2.75 A, UNLESS the process depends on the radius of the hydrated metal ions. Can anyone point me to an article that describes the radius of hydrated sodium and chloride ions? (I'm assuming that the number of water molecules surrounding a sodium ion is 6, not sure what the number of water molecules surrounding chloride is). Even though the van Der Waals forces are weak, these must be important for ionic flow through a reverse osmosis membrane.